# How to sort an associative array in ascending & descending order based on a key that contains the UNIX time stamp value?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array, key-value

I've an associative array titled `$things` as follows :

Note : I'm putting below only few elements from the associative array `$things` for understanding purpose only. The actual array is very huge and contains lots of such inner arrays.

Below is the output of statement `print_r($things);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [is_liked] => 
            [comment_id] => 1654
            [parent_id] => 0
            [type_id] => image
            [item_id] => 141
            [user_id] => 901
            [owner_user_id] => 901
            [time_stamp] => 1438072030
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [is_liked] => 
            [comment_id] => 1657
            [parent_id] => 0
            [type_id] => poll
            [item_id] => 141
            [user_id] => 901
            [owner_user_id] => 901
            [time_stamp] => 1438080858
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [is_liked] => 
            [comment_id] => 1658
            [parent_id] => 0
            [type_id] => poll
            [item_id] => 141
            [user_id] => 901
            [owner_user_id] => 901
            [time_stamp] => 1438082006
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [is_liked] => 
            [comment_id] => 1659
            [parent_id] => 0
            [type_id] => poll
            [item_id] => 141
            [user_id] => 901
            [owner_user_id] => 901
            [time_stamp] => 1438083448
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [is_liked] => 
            [comment_id] => 1660
            [parent_id] => 0
            [type_id] => poll
            [item_id] => 141
            [user_id] => 901
            [owner_user_id] => 901
            [time_stamp] => 1438083459

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [is_liked] => 
            [comment_id] => 1661
            [parent_id] => 0
            [type_id] => text
            [item_id] => 141
            [user_id] => 901
            [owner_user_id] => 901
            [time_stamp] => 1438083467
         )

)
```

Can someone help me out by helping me in sorting the above associative array in ascending and descending order based on time stamp value which is present in every inner array.

The mechanism to sort the array must be efficient and reliable since the array may contain huge amount of data which is to be sorted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `usort` as

**Ascending**

```
usort($your_array,function($a,$b){
    return $a['time_stamp'] - $b['time_stamp'];
});
```

**Descending**

```
usort($your_array,function($a,$b){
    return $b['time_stamp'] - $a['time_stamp'];
});
```

Note : Not Tested

Comment: I want two separate mechanisms for sorting the associative array in ascending and descending order both. Could you please provide me the same?

Comment: First of all thanks for your help. One more small help I need from you. The sorting is working absolutely fine but after sorting the keys of the inner array are not getting change. They are supposed to start from 0 till the end of array. Can you please make the necessary change to your answer, so that I'd accept your answer finally? Thanks once again.

Comment: Instead of `uasort` try using `usort` check my updated answer `uasort` is used for preserving keys too

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_multisort](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for this.

Comment: Its more likely to be a comment instead

Comment: I want two separate mechanisms for sorting the associative array in ascending and descending order both. Could you please provide me the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have implementeed same functionality using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($newArray, array($things, 'sort'));
```

Comment: I want two separate mechanisms for sorting the associative array in ascending and descending order both. Could you please provide me the same?

Comment: you can use krsort() function to sort array in descending order